# PyQGIS Output leads to invisible layers that don't appear in the layer panel or the canvas but can be accessed in Vector tools

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm working on a Processing Tool in PyQGIS and am struggling with the problem described in the title.
Layers are not visible in the "Layers Panel" or on the canvas but can be chosen and worked with in tools like Buffer or Dissolve.

I have 2 variations that produce the same result.
One looks like this:

```
        poolLayer = processing.run('native:dissolve', {
            'INPUT': outputs['ReprojectPoolkarte']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(poolLayer)
```

The other case looks like this:

```
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'Flaeche_Pool',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 2,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FORMULA': 'Flaeche_A/poolFl',
            'INPUT': outputs['AttributeNachFeldwert']['OUTPUT'],
            'NEW_FIELD': True,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Flaeche_PoolFieldCalculator'] = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['ErgebnisNeanteileFinal'] = outputs['Flaeche_PoolFieldCalculator']['OUTPUT']
        
        layer = context.takeResultLayer(outputs['AttributeNachFeldwert']['OUTPUT'])     
        transform_context = QgsCoordinateTransformContext()
        save_options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
        save_options.driverName = "CSV"
        save_options.overrideGeometryType = QgsWkbTypes.Point
        save_options.fileEncoding = "System"
        save_options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layer, r'c:\temp\output.csv', transform_context, save_options)
        
        return results
```

This actually works fine until I add the part of the code for exporting the layer as a CSV-File as well.
In both case the resulting layers are fine but I have to make them "visible" by manually running them through a buffer with 0m or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, check if `layer` is an instance of `QgsVectorLayer`.

```
layer = ...
print(type(layer))
```

If so, then, you **have to** add the following method to your processing algorithm class to be able to add temporary layers to the "Layers Panel".

```
def flags(self):
    return super().flags() | QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading
```

Then use this::

```
layer = ...
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()(0, layer)
```

The first command registers the layer. The second adds it to the layer panel. I am not entirely sure why this works, but I always do it..

Comment: now I get this Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 63, in processAlgorithm
TypeError: 'QgsLayerTree' object is not callable

Comment: Did you type LayerTree or LayerTreeRoot?

Comment: I copied your code exactly only changed the name of the layer.

Comment: QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer() returns None if it didn't work. Maybe test your original code for that.

Comment: thing is addMapLayer() must have worked, the layer is definitly there, I can Buffer it with 0m and it will show up perfectly finde. it just doesn't show in the Layer Panel before that.... very confusing to me.

Comment: Try saving the project and opening it again.

Comment: Thanks for that. I copied and pasted badly today...